# How to fix CA certification problems with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, curl, openssl, rvm, heroku-toolbelt

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 one week ago and I'm facing a serious issue which causes chained problems.

The main issue is **CA certification** and/or **CA bundle** stuff.

Honestly, I'm not very clear about these concepts.

All I can guess is it's related to `cURL` and `openssl`.

But whenever I try to install **RVM**, whenever I try to install **Heroku Toolbelt** and whenever I try to connect programmatically to a site which has **SSL**; I see errors.

One of them is :
`Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.`

Another one is:
`curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK`

I think this is an essential issue which influces any new installation of Ubuntu. Is this correct?

I've been googling since days... I couldn't find a certain solution. I downloaded `cacert.pem`  and copied to `/usr/share/ca-certificates` and some other places... And then I edited something like ca-certicate.conf. But I'm lost. I think *nix world needs a clean answer to this.

I don't remember that I had got this error until my last installation. So at the moment, this issue is a black hole for me.

So,

#### Can someone please explain what is this CA certification problem with CURL and how to fix it on Ubuntu?

Note: I didn't ask this at askubuntu.com because I think issue is not Ubuntu specific.

Comment: You may want to post this question to http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I installed Cygwin and tried to use cURL. The problem went away when I downloaded the `*.pem` file containing the certificates from the cURL page using [this link](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and then adding the `--cacert [file]` flag to the command. Here is an example:

```
// here I'm assuming the *.pem file is in the current directory
curl --cacert cacert.pem -i -v -L --cookie-jar "cookies.txt" -X POST --data "SOME_PRIVATE_DATA_HERE" https://www.mywebpage.com
```

[This link](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) has some more instructions (I used #2)

Hope this helps!